# Laravel - How to do nested where with And and OR in same query

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a following query

```
$updates = FolderLocker::where('created_at', 'like', $date . '%')
                ->orWhere('date_forwarded', 'like', $date . '%')
                ->orWhere('date_locked', 'like', $date . '%')
                ->orWhere('date_completed', 'like', $date . '%')
                ->whereIn('videographer_id', $videographerArray)
                ->orderBy('client_id', 'DESC')

                ->toSql();
```

It generates

```
select * from `folder_lockers` where `created_at` like ? or `date_forwarded` like ? or `date_locked` like ? or `date_completed` like ? and `videographer_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) order by `client_id` desc
```

How can I make the `whereIn` clause the main one and then all the `OR` clauses in another AND?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group your wheres in a closure, like this:

```
$updates = FolderLocker::whereIn('videographer_id', $videographerArray)
               ->where(function ($query) use ($date) {
                   $query->where('created_at', 'like', $date . '%')
                       ->orWhere('date_forwarded', 'like', $date . '%')
                       ->orWhere('date_locked', 'like', $date . '%')
                       ->orWhere('date_completed', 'like', $date . '%');
               })                
               ->orderBy('client_id', 'DESC');
```